# (PySide6) How can I run QMediaPlayer in separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyside6, qmediaplayer

I am trying to process every `QVideoFrame` from `QMediaPlayer` and display it on `QLabel`.

Here is the sample code.

1. `QMediaPlayer` sends `QVideoFrame` to `QVideoSink`
2. Video sink sends the frame to `MyWorker`.
3. `MyWorker` converts `QVideoFrame` to `QPixmap`, does some processing and sends the pixmap to `QLabel`.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Signal, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QVideoSink, QVideoFrame
import sys
import time


class MyWorker(QObject):

    pixmapChanged = Signal(QPixmap)

    @Slot(QVideoFrame)
    def setVideoFrame(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        qimg = frame.toImage()
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # represents time-consuming work
        self.pixmapChanged.emit(pixmap)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

player = QMediaPlayer()
sink = QVideoSink()
worker = MyWorker()
widget = QLabel()

player.setVideoSink(sink)
sink.videoFrameChanged.connect(worker.setVideoFrame)
worker.pixmapChanged.connect(widget.setPixmap)
player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("my-video.mp4"))

widget.show()
player.play()
app.exec()
app.quit()
```

Processing takes some time, so the label is updating slower than the original video FPS. This is fine, but the problem is that my current code without `QThread` is blocking the GUI.

Using `player.moveToThread(...)` didn't work. How can I run `QMediaPlayer` in separate thread?

Comment: I'm not sure that QMediaPlayer actually supports working in a separate thread, most importantly because it normally uses the system multimedia backend, so it doesn't *directly* play the media, it's just an interface. The main question here is: does it need to be real time? Besides, I would start by moving the worker in an actual separate thread (it would require some fixing, though).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. I don't need my video to be real time (I don't mind if the displayed fps is slower than the original fps). Perhaps I have to run a worker in another thread and send the video frame to it?

Comment: That's exactly my point. Since you don't need real time processing, you may have to rethink the whole approach. Remember that QMediaPlayer is, as the name suggests, a *player*. You don't need to *play* the video, you need to *process* it. If I were you, I'd consider other external libraries: a possibility is to use ffmpeg, run internally with QProcess with piping of the output, so that you can receive every frame in the separate thread and eventually process it just as it was an image.

Comment: For anyone who may want to do the same, I developed a small package for this purpose: https://github.com/JSS95/araviq6

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @musicamente, I fixed it by moving the worker to separate thread.

Note that the window sends the frame to worker only when the worker is ready. If not, blocked signals are queued with `QVideoFrame` instance and quickly consume all the memory.

## Media player

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot, QThread, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QVideoSink, QVideoFrame
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel
import time


class FrameWorker(QObject):

    pixmapChanged = Signal(QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ready = True

    @Slot(QVideoFrame)
    def setVideoFrame(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        self.ready = False
        time.sleep(1)  # represents time-consuming work
        self.pixmapChanged.emit(QPixmap.fromImage(frame.toImage()))
        self.ready = True


class FrameSender(QObject):
    frameChanged = Signal(QVideoFrame)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.workerThread = QThread()
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.frameSender = FrameSender()
        self.frameWorker = FrameWorker()
        self.displayLabel = QLabel()

        self.frameWorker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.workerThread.start()

        self.player.setVideoSink(QVideoSink(self))
        self.player.videoSink().videoFrameChanged.connect(self.onFramePassedFromPlayer)
        self.frameSender.frameChanged.connect(self.frameWorker.setVideoFrame)
        self.frameWorker.pixmapChanged.connect(self.displayLabel.setPixmap)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.displayLabel)

    @Slot(QVideoFrame)
    def onFramePassedFromPlayer(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        if self.frameWorker.ready:
            self.frameSender.frameChanged.emit(frame)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.workerThread.quit()
        self.workerThread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("my-video.mp4"))
    window.show()
    window.player.play()
    app.exec()
    app.quit()
```

## Camera

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot, QThread
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaCaptureSession, QVideoSink, QVideoFrame, QCamera
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel
import time


class FrameWorker(QObject):

    pixmapChanged = Signal(QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ready = True

    @Slot(QVideoFrame)
    def setVideoFrame(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        self.ready = False
        time.sleep(1)  # represents time-consuming work
        self.pixmapChanged.emit(QPixmap.fromImage(frame.toImage()))
        self.ready = True


class FrameSender(QObject):
    frameChanged = Signal(QVideoFrame)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.workerThread = QThread()
        self.captureSession = QMediaCaptureSession()
        self.frameSender = FrameSender()
        self.frameWorker = FrameWorker()
        self.displayLabel = QLabel()

        self.frameWorker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.workerThread.start()

        self.captureSession.setVideoSink(QVideoSink(self))
        self.captureSession.videoSink().videoFrameChanged.connect(
            self.onFramePassedFromCamera
        )
        self.frameSender.frameChanged.connect(self.frameWorker.setVideoFrame)
        self.frameWorker.pixmapChanged.connect(self.displayLabel.setPixmap)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.displayLabel)

        camera = QCamera(self)
        self.captureSession.setCamera(camera)
        camera.start()

    @Slot(QVideoFrame)
    def onFramePassedFromCamera(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        if self.frameWorker.ready:
            self.frameSender.frameChanged.emit(frame)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.workerThread.quit()
        self.workerThread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
    app.quit()
```

Comment: Note: QPixmap is not thread-safe, so you shall *never* create a QPixmap in an external thread. Emit the QImage and do the `QPixmap.fromImage` in the main thread instead.